# Multipeer Bluetooth Connection to non-iOS device

Tags: ios, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth, multipeer-connectivity

I am currently trying to connect a Raspberry Pi and an iOS device via Bluetooth. Using BTLE and the `CBCentralManager` I am able to do this - I can connect to the Pi and share data.

My problem is that for my purpose I need the devices to have an IP - which, as far as I know, is only possible using a PAN (Personal Area Network) bluetooth profile. iOS does support this with the new [Multipeer Connectivity Framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MultipeerConnectivity/Reference/MultipeerConnectivityFramework/Introduction/Introduction.html) and it works when connecting two iOS devices, one using `MCNearbyServiceBrowser` and the other using `MCNearbyServiceAdvertiser`. After the connection was made both devices have a network interface with an IP. But now I have to get the Rasperry Pi into that scenario - and I cannot find any way to make the Pi join the PAN.

Does anyone have any clues if this is somehow possible, where to start looking, if there is a good explanation about the communication in a PAN or something similar? Could there maybe even be a framework that does something like that? I am happy for any leads and advices.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Multipeer Connectivity Framework probably is probably based on a proprietary protocol as I have nowhere seen that it implements PAN. It's only similar to it. As you mention, the list of supported [profiles](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht3647) contains PAN as well with the following note:

> Depending on the Bluetooth accessory, you may experience slight
>   variations in profile functionality. These variations are governed by
>   the accessory manufacturer, not the iOS device.

So in theory PAN is supported as is, and you should be able to connect with an arbitrary device that supports this profile. I connected my Android phone to my iPhone with the Personal Hotspot on the iPhone and the Android could use the shared internet connection without any issues.

I found the [Raspberry Pi Bluetooth iPhone Tethering](http://www.wolfteck.com/projects/raspi/iphone/) tutorial that seems to describe exactly what you are trying to do. For future reference I copy the steps here:

**Install the bluetooth packages**

```
sudo aptitude install bluetooth bluez-utils bluez-compat
```

**Pair the devices, this is the tricky part**

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ hcitool scan
Scanning ...
    18:34:51:55:B0:D8   Fanboy ][
pi@raspberrypi ~ $
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ grep KeyboardDisplay /usr/bin/bluez-simple-agent 
    capability = "KeyboardDisplay"
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ sudo perl -i -pe 's/KeyboardDisplay/DisplayYesNo/' /usr/bin/bluez-simple-agent
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ grep DisplayYesNo /usr/bin/bluez-simple-agent
    capability = "DisplayYesNo"
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ 
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ sudo bluez-simple-agent hci0 18:34:51:55:B0:D8
RequestConfirmation (/org/bluez/18868/hci0/dev_18_34_51_55_B0_D8, 160178)
Confirm passkey (yes/no): yes
Release
New device (/org/bluez/18868/hci0/dev_18_34_51_55_B0_D8)
pi@raspberrypi ~ $
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ sudo bluez-test-device trusted 18:34:51:55:B0:D8 yes
```

**Turn on the Personal Hotspot**

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ echo "echo 'iface bnep0 inet dhcp' >> /etc/network/interfaces" | sudo sh
pi@raspberrypi ~ 

$ sudo pand -c 18:34:51:55:B0:D8 -role PANU --persist 30
```

**Enjoy**

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ ifconfig bnep0
bnep0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr e0:91:53:61:0f:74  
          inet addr:172.20.10.10  Bcast:172.20.10.15  Mask:255.255.255.240
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:14 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:7 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:4426 (4.3 KiB)  TX bytes:802 (802.0 B)
```

All credits go to http://www.wolfteck.com/ for providing these detailed instructions.

Comment: thank you very much. unfortunately, I cannot test this until the beginning of next week, but I will report back as soon as I did.

Comment: Note that on iOS (unlike Android), you need to enable mobile data in order to activate personal hotspot.

Comment: Well, I finally came down to testing this: It does indeed work (more or less), but the problem I am having is that I want to _programmatically_ connect to a bluez PAN from an iOS device, and I still can't see how I can do that? In fact, usingt `MCNearbyServiceBrowser` does not seem to be noticed by the pi at all. Can I somehow sniff the BT packets sent by the iphone to maybe find out more about this?

Comment: You won't be able to do that. Only the user can modify any network settings.

Comment: The Multipeer Framework is a proprietary, closed source protocol. Additionally, it requires the MFi authenticator chip to make such a connection (hence only iOS devices are connectable.) So even if you could reverse engineer the protocol, you wouldn't be able to make any connections. On a non-Jailbroken iOS device the way I described is the only thing you can do, anything else with bluetooth requires MFi.

Comment: That's too bad... considering I am developing an internal app and can use private APIs like the `BluetoothManager`, is there any good way to do this? An alternative could be to manually open an ad-hoc wifi network using private APIs, but I couldn't find anything useful on how to do that so far...

Comment: I haven't looked into the private APIs. It may be possible to do that. You should ask this in a different question I'm interested in learning something new too. Btw, do you think I answered this question? If so, then please accept it. Thanks.

Comment: @allprog How do you know that the Multipeer Framework requires an MFi chip? Does this also apply in the Wifi-only (i.e. non-Bluetooth) operation mode?

Comment: Only the supported bluetooth profiles need no authenticator chip https://support.apple.com/hu-hu/HT204387. MC is unfortunately not listed there.